# Amazon Web Services public datasets

Tags: amazon-web-services, dataset, bigdata

Is there any way to directly download a public dataset from AWS?
For instance, here is this public dataset:
https://aws.amazon.com/datasets/daily-global-weather-measurements-1929-2009-ncdc-gsod/
So far it seems to me that the only way to access it is to create an account, launch up a virtual machine with some storage (which is not free of course) and analyze the data in the cloud. 
So is there a simple way to download the data via a direct link as it is advertised as free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically - I have seen the datasets weigh few 10s to 100s of GBs and more. I don't think if that is practical to download and inspect the data. Many of the datasets are direct EBS snapshots and the process involved in consuming the datasets is just creating a volume and mounting it to your instance.

I get a feel you don't have an AWS account and I strongly recommend to create one and leverage the free trial and launch t2.micro instance and give it a try.  It wouldn't cost much, of course EBS's cost would span beyond the free-tier.

Please consider operating the data given by AWS from AWS.

Comment: Thank you! Just in case someone wants to actually download it, here is a copy: ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/gsod